# Magento Backoffice Catalog->Product slow

Tags: magento

I have a issue in my Magento Backoffice. 
If i try to browser Catalog-> Manage products it takes up to 15seconds to open the page (20 results per page). Also if I try to move from page 1 to page 2 of the results it takes the same time.
If i open all other section menu of backoffice it takes maximum 0.5 sec.

Please note i have 160.000 sku in Magento
I am on a dedicated server with 24 Gb RAM and 250 SSD RAID 1
I have FastCgi Ngnix APC Memcached installed

It's this log delay  maybe related to same table issue?

How can a 20 page result take all this time to open?

Answer (score 0):

Things looks better now,

here what i did:

I discovered core_url_rewrite table was over 5 gb !!!
and Flat catalog and Flat categry in Magento backoffice where setted on "No".

I did a trucante of core_url_rewrite and enabled Flat Catalog and Poduct in magento backoffice.

I then did a full reindex.

Now timing is decreased from 15 sec  to 4-6 seconds.

Hope it can help someone